# Can't import vue2-google-maps component to main.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue2-google-maps

After installing vue2-google-maps with npm, I'm trying to import the component to my main.js. But I keep getting an error. I never had problem importing packages to main.js or to other .vue files.

Versions:
vue 2.6.10
vue2-google-maps@0.10.7
vue-cli 2.9.6 but also tried with 3.11.0

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store/store.js";
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.use(
  VueGoogleMaps,
  {
    load: {
      key: "AIzaSyBYULuuIqKYMJVrEk1PjpUDQQYkGMmP0iM",
      libraries: 'places'
    }
  }
);
```

I'm getting the error in this line : import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

> **Error Message:**  Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue2-google-maps'.
>   'c:/Users/BotiVegh/vueJS_projects/vue-store-gallery-map/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/main.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/vue2-google-maps` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
>   file containing `declare module 'vue2-google-maps';`ts(7016)

Do I need to change something in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `"noImplicitAny": false` to your **tsconfig.json** file

This disables warnings on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type

Comment: there is no file called tsconfig.json in laravel